# Excel Vba: Finding the Bookmark before a Table on a Word Document

Tags: vba, ms-word

Is there anyway to find the bookmark that exists before a specified table on a word document?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the bookmarks `Start` or `End` (range) property to get the ordering of the bookmarks.

```
Public Sub TestIt()

    Dim bm1 As Bookmark
    Dim bm2 As Bookmark

    Set bm1 = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Bookmark1")
    Set bm2 = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Bookmark2")

    If bm1.Start < bm2.Start Then
        MsgBox "bm1 is before bm2"
    ElseIf bm1.Start > bm2.Start Then
        MsgBox "bm2 is before bm1"
    Else
        MsgBox "bm1 and bm2 start at the same place"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What if the second bookmark is always changing?

Comment: The start/end property values will adjust with the bookmarks range as it's moved, such as adding additional text for example.  however, if you were to save the start property to an int/long then move the bookmark range, then that start value would be obsolete and require updating.